# What is the maximum sample rate/bit depth of the iPhone for recording?

Tags: iphone, sample-rate, bit-depth

Hello.

I've been wondering for a while now about the recording capabilities of my iPhone. With the addition of the Apogee Mic and others it could be a good little recorder maybe?

But I wonder, does any one know the maximum sample rate / bit depth of the iPhone?

I personally have the iPhone 4 with iOS 5.

Thanks! James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99.9% sure it's 48kHz, 16-bit Mono (or Stereo if you have a plug-in mic of some sort which supports Stereo).  I use the FiRe app which is one of the most comprehensive and professional-geared recording apps, and that's the max it supports.  On older iPhones like the 3G I believe it was only 44.1kHz.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And just so everyone who searches for this question, after you said about the FiRe app, I contacted the Audiofile Engineering guys and asked about this, their response was: "FiRe 2 records @ 48 kHz/16-bit. In a future update, we'll allow users to change the sample rate of their recordings so they're not limited to just 48 kHz." ...I do hope that Apple will allow future iPhones/iPod Touches to support 24bit as along with a decent iDevice compatible microphone (the Apogee Mic?) it could be a very handy and portable quick and dirty sound recording device.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, recording with 24bit depth is a waste of space if a mobile phone is within half a meter of the recording equipment, let alone if it *is* the recording equipment.

Your phones uses high powered bursts of pulsed RF to talk to the next cell tower (which will tend to be at some distance) regularly.  Do yourself a favor and get some more dedicated recording equipment.

As a rule of thumb: built-in electret condensor mic capsules of the kind that fit within phones or handheld recorders have enough of a relevant noise floor that recording with more than 16bit resolution is nonsensical.  You can fill in the 8 additional bits of resolution with a good random number generator afterwards for equivalent results.

The preamps and mics necessary to warrant going to more than 16bit have power and space requirements incompatible with a mobile phone.

Given how popular requests for 96/24 on clearly unsuitable recording equipment are, I have little doubt that we'll be seeing a marketing push to 192/32 bit recording soonish and 384/48 bit next.  Flash memory producers will love it.

Answer (score -1):

you can actually put 48 KHz / 24 bits on the iPhone. when you import from a CD onto iTunes, the maximum is 48 KHz /16 bits

Comment: CD format is 44.1kHz,16-bit. Not 48kHz.